# How to change the color of the button title in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Is-it possible to change the color of the Title for the button ?

Because this code d'ont work

```
btnLogin.titleColor = UIColor.darkGray
```

Comment: Usually, use `setTitleColor(_:for:)` because buttons can have different `UIControlState`: `.normal`, `.highlighted`, `.selected`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
btnLogin.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

As the other comments says, use

```
    btnLogin.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGray, for: .normal)
```

Here you can read the explanation of this method and the different states (normal, selected, highlighted, ...)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623993-settitlecolor

Answer (score 1):

You can set like this:

```
button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
```